# import Error: realvnc sdk

Tags: python, python-2.7, vnc, vnc-viewer

I would like to use RealVNC python api for one of my script.

So, I am trying to install realVNC for Python on my Windows 7 system. 
As I read the documentation on [realvnc](https://developer.realvnc.com/docs/latest/api/python/index.html) developer site many times,
The documentation is not really clear enough. 
Technically, I've done the following steps;

1. I  registered on realvnc website
2. Next, I  downloaded the vncsdk-1.4.0 and extracted on my pc
3. Next, I copied "vncsdk.py" file to "C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages"
4. Next, I copied "vncsdk.dll" file to "C:\Windows\System32"
5. Finally , I created a system variable named "VNCSDK_LIBRARY" and variable value is: "C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\;C:\Windows\System32\;

But, Unfortunately it does not work for me. When I try to import the module from a python script, it gives me the following error;

```
>>> import vncsdk
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\vncsdk.py", line 144, in <module>
    VNCSDK_LIBRARY = _find_library()
  File "C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\vncsdk.py", line 134, in _find_library
    raise ImportError("could not find the SDK shared object: VNCSDK_LIBRARY is n
ot a file or directory")
ImportError: could not find the SDK shared object: VNCSDK_LIBRARY is not a file
or directory
>>>
```

Any helps would be appreciated.

Comment: What if you copy `vncsdk.py` to the same source directory?

Comment: Thanks for your comment @xuhdev. I've already tried before. Unfortunately that did not help at all. it gives me the same error.

Comment: how did you creat the environmental variable? Did you restart the cmd window afterwards?

Comment: Yes. I tried more than 10 times. I also tried "vncsdk.py" with the same project directory.

Comment: import os
import vncsdk

os.environ['VNCSDK_LIBRARY'] = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'resources')
print('SDK library found at: ' + vncsdk.VNCSDK_LIBRARY)

Comment: python test.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 2, in <module>
    import vncsdk
  File "C:\Users\yke01\Documents\StormTest\Scripts\Completed\Utils\SU04Conversio
n\vncsdk.py", line 144, in <module>
    VNCSDK_LIBRARY = _find_library()
  File "C:\Users\yke01\Documents\StormTest\Scripts\Completed\Utils\SU04Conversio
n\vncsdk.py", line 134, in _find_library
    raise ImportError("could not find the SDK shared object: VNCSDK_LIBRARY is n
ot a file or directory")
ImportError: could not find the SDK shared object: VNCSDK_LIBRARY is not a file
or directory

Answer (score 0):

In your script, you should Set VNCSDK_LIBRARY before you import vncsdk.

Comment: Thanks once again for your help.  C:\Windows\System32;C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages; I just updated system variable. But unfortunately it still gives me the same error as above.

Comment: @yakupme Did you do this in your code? Moved the import line after the os.environ line

Comment: Yes, I did. But unfortunately it still gives me the same error.

Comment: @yakupme try to set VNCSDK_LIBRARY to the path to the library, not the dir.